# Python MYSQLDB Insert Syntax Error

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to insert data into my database and I get a MYSQL syntax error using this code:

```
import MySQLdb
db=MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="",db="database")
cursor = db.cursor()
sql = "INSERT INTO table1('col1','col2') values ('val1','val2');"
cursor.execute(sql)
db.commit()
```

Comment: What was the syntax error that you got? Edit your question.

Answer (score 2):

No quotes around the column names.

```
INSERT INTO table1(col1, col2) VALUES ('val1', 'val2');
```

You could use backticks around the column names, but not single quotes.

Comment: What do you mean, can you paste the code that you're referring to? I see quotes around them.

Comment: @NoahR: he means "quotes not allowed around column names"